# Error when trying to calculate column average - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe so when I try to calculate the mean of column A I just write

```
mean(df$A)
```

and it works fine.

But when I try to calculate mean of only part of the data frame I get an error saying it isn't a number or logical value

```
df$A %>% filter(A=="some value") %>% mean(df$A)
```

The type of A is double. I also tried to convert it to numeric using

```
df$A <- as.numeric(as.character(df$A))
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `df$A` by doing this we are converting dataframe column into a vector, and `filter` has no idea what "A" means. Try: `names(mtcars[, "mpg", drop = FALSE])` vs `names(mtcars$mpg)`

Comment: Ohh.. Thats the answer I needed!! Thanks.. So everytime I convert a df column into a vector, it changes its type ? but if I use names(mtcars[1]) it knows its mpg...

Comment: Right, now compare `mtcars[1]` vs `mtcars[[1]]`. It is about how you subset, dataframe is just a list that can hold other types with the same length.

Comment: are the cars names like index values?? I can see choosing mtcars[[1]] keeps it numeric though..

Comment: I suggest do some basic R course. Car names are the row names, try `rownames(mtcars)`.

Comment: I should start one next semester though i'm really having hard times with it now.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could start with the comprehensive introduction to R and build on it. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df %>% filter(A==some value) %>% summarise(mean(A))`.

> Note that the mean will be `some value` because of the `filter`.
>   Also, `mean()` works fine with objects of class `double`

Comment: Thanks!! it works.. it is really strange.. I don't understand why filtering by some criterion suddenly makes it non-numerical??

Comment: Normally it shouldn't. Here is an example with the `iris` dataset: `iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length == 4.8) %>% summarise(mean(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: or `df %>% filter(A==some value) %>% pull(A) %>% mean()`

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to provide an example of your column A.

However, by just looking to your question the problem is in your magrittr-dplyr syntax.

*base* syntax:

```
mean(df$A[df$A == 'some value'])
```

*dplyr* with pipes:

```
df %>% filter(A==2) %>% summarise(., average = mean(A))
```

Careful with syntax and pipes, more info [here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org).

Comment: That's actually much easier than using pipes!! Thanks! :)